# Bootstrap-table: Grid system - How to put image with width in different rows and the same column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show in the window-modal the info and image of a product but I do not know to put an image with it large is various rows of the grid.

My code is:

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 descFields impFields">
                            CODI
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 .offset-md5">   
                            <img class='img-modal' src='prod/images/nofoto.jpg'>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 descFields impFields">
                            EDICIÓ
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 descFields impFields">
                            PÀGINA
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">

                        </div> 
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 descFields impFields">
                            MODIF.
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 descFields impFields">
                            USER
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">

                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I would like that all columns are in the same distance:

[image]

I'm trying to use offset parameters and child parameters but It's not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite your code structure..

```
          <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-12 descFields impFields">
                        CODI
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-12 descFields impFields">
                        EDICIÓ
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-12 descFields impFields">
                        PÀGINA
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-12 descFields impFields">
                        MODIF.
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-12 descFields impFields">
                        USER
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6">   
                  <img class='img-modal' src='prod/images/nofoto.jpg'>
               </div>
            </div>
```

divide grid in 2 section first section for data and second for image...

Comment: FYI - You removed OP's placeholders for the value fields.

Comment: oops.. just divide left block into 2 block of col-md-6 i.e. col-md-6 for label and col-md-6 for data section